# Flutter Firestore Automatically create new Document when editing Field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling data from Firestore and Editing, and when I click on the data to `edit`, I don't see it showing anything, however when I write the information and Save. Instead of changing the Edited Field, I get a new `document` with the edited `field`.

For example in the code, I edit the `name` => I will have a new `document` with the `email` reused and `name` changed.

And here is my code:

```
class EditHouse extends StatefulWidget {
  final House house;
  EditHouse(this.house);

class _EditHouseState extends State<EditHouse> {
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();

@override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.house == null) {
      nameController.text == "";
      emailController.text == "";
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final houseProvider =
            Provider.of<HouseProvider>(context, listen: false);
        houseProvider.loadValues(House(
            name: '',
            email: ''));
      });
    } else {
      nameController.text = widget.house.name;
      emailController.text = widget.house.email;
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final houseProvider =
            Provider.of<HouseProvider>(context, listen: false);
        houseProvider.loadValues(widget.house);
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }}
```

I don't know if the problem lies here or not `EditHouse(this.house);`

when I can't use it `EditHouse([required this.house]);` I will get an error message `Can't have modifier 'required' here`

Comment: I try `EditHouse({required this.house});` But also failed

Comment: sorry where in the code are you calling firestore? What does houseProvider.loadValues do? is it important? if it is, would you mind showing its code?

Comment: @h8moss I successfully fixed it yesterday at houseProvider. But on my code I can't show what I need to see `nameController.text = widget.house.name;` it seems to be an empty field